# SurfaceView shows blacks screen?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am trying to get my SurfaceView to work but I am getting black Screen. I tried to change the color number of `canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);` but it was not helpful. I do not know what the reason is. I appreciate any help!

```js
package com.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MyBringBackSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

 SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
 Thread ourThread = null;
 boolean isRunning;

 public MyBringBackSurface(Context context) {
  super(context);
  ourHolder = getHolder();
  ourThread = new Thread(this);
  ourThread.start();

 }

 @Override
 public void run() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  while (isRunning) {
   if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
    continue;
   Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
   canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);
   ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
  }

 }

}
```

Comment: Are you setting `isRunning` to true anywhere?  Can you confirm that the run() loop ever tries to execute?  Do you know if this is a problem with the surface and rendering, or with the threading and execution of the program?

Comment: Thanks  for your comment. yep I forgot to assign isRunning to true.